# Why does mysql binlog use different isolation level?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Default isolation level:

```
mysql> SELECT @@TX_ISOLATION;
+-----------------+
| @@TX_ISOLATION  |
+-----------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Binlog:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000078 --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS
....
/*!50718 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED*//*!*/;
```

What is the reason for using different level isolation in binlog?
How it can affect an application code written for `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level?

Comment: What value do you have for `innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog`? Do individual connections change `tx_isolation`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are no concurrent threads during replication or data recovery process, so a lower isolation level helps us to avoid unnecessary locks and speed up the process.

Comment: Not so much concurrency, but its already committed on whatever generated the master, so additional checks aren't needed. What binlog_format? Does this make a difference?

Comment: @danblack binlog format is ROW

Answer (score 0):

The code that outputs that line in the mysqlbinlog output is preceded by this comment:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/trunk/sql/log_event.cc#L12999-L13011

> ```
> /*
>     The applier thread can always use "READ COMMITTED" isolation for
>     transactions containing only RBR events (Table_map + Rows).
>
>     This would prevent some deadlock issues because InnoDB doesn't
>     acquire GAP locks in "READ COMMITTED" isolation level since
>     MySQL 5.7.18.
>   */
> ```